# Sobrepor Elementos

Tags: xamarin-forms, xaml

Boa tarde

Sou novo em Xamarin e estou tendo problemas em sobrepor elementos.
Eu fiz algumas tentativas, mas sem sucesso.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15"></BoxView>
    </Frame>
    <Button  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Accent"  Text="Recados" Command="{Binding SwitchToTabCommand}" CommandParameter="4"></Button>

</Grid>
```

Será que alguém consegue me dizer onde está o erro ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu descobri um jeito. Mudei o backgroud q eu queria para o frame e deixei o do button transparente. O que estava acontecendo era que o botão estava ficando por cima do frame e quando eu coloquei o backgroud, ele tampou o BoxView.

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Accent" >
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15"></BoxView>
</Frame>
<Button  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Text="Recados" Command="{Binding SwitchToTabCommand}" CommandParameter="4"></Button>
```